# Int considered as bool, & operator

Tags: c++, operators, boolean, int

I've been struggling for a while with a part of my code and I finally found that the problem lies with a simple test that don't give me the result I expect.

```
if (2) //=> true
if (2 & true) //=> false
if (bool(2) & true) //=> true
```

What I don't understand is why the second line results in false.
My understanding was that every non-zero integer was considered as true in a test.

Comment: `&` is the bit wise operator, `&&` is the logical and operator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the **bitwise and** between `2` and `true` is false.

`&` (bitwise operator) is different than `&&` (logical operator).

`true` cast to `int` is `1`.

So `2 & true` is `2 & 1` which is false - because `0000000000000010 & 0000000000000001 == 0`. (bits may vary)

Whereas `bool(2) == 1`, and `1 & 1` is `true`.

Comment: When you have time, would you look at my answer to the same question?  The reason I ask is that my answer hesitates over a point of the C++11 standard and a compiler's (or CPU's?) behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: is it specified anywhere than `true` should be converted to `1` when an integral is needed, or would any positive integral value be okay as far as the standard is concerned (for example: `0b11111111`) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I believe any value other than `0` is `true`, but that `true` is converted to one, yes. Don't have time to look for a quote right now though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In C++03 it was 4.5, Integral promotions, paragraph 4, "An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one."

Answer (score 4):

```
if (2) //=> true
```

So far, so good.

```
if (2 & true) //=> false
```

The condition here evaluates to `2 & 1 == 0`, because `&` is a bitwise operator and 2 and 1 are respectively 00000010 and 00000001 in binary.

```
if (bool(2) & true) //=> true
```

Interestingly enough, on my compiler I seem to recall erratic behavior in some cases like this; and, if sect. 4.12 of the C++11 standard addresses the matter, it does so in a manner I do not understand.  I seem to recall seeing my compiler let `bool(2) == 2`, which one would not expect.  Whether this represents a bug in my compiler or a fault in my recollection, I do not know.

I suspect however that you want the logical operator `&&` rather than the bitwise operator `&`.

**QUIZ**

To check your understanding, try

```
if (3 & true) //=> true
```

Do you understand why?  (Hint:  the binary representation of 3 is 00000011.)

Comment: If `bool(2) == 2`, then something is definitely wrong. Either the compiler is misbehaving, or you have an evil header containing something like `#define bool int`· Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  GCC 4.4 (which, I am aware, is not mostly C++11 compliant, but one doubts that the version of the standard in use is the issue here).  However, following your comment, I cannot now reproduce the behavior, though I *seem* to remember encountering it within the past year.  Sorry for wasting your time.  If I encounter the behavior again in an up-to-date compiler, I should file an appropriate bug report with GCC's developers.  For the present, I will edit my answer here shortly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need `&&` instead of `&`.

`&&` is the boolean `and` operator, whereas `&` is the binary 'and' so `2 & true` is the same as `0010 & 0001 = 0000 -> false` whereas `2 && true = true`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` does an AND between all the bits (call bitwise AND) , what you need is the `&&` operator (boolean AND).

2 in binary is '10' and true is 1 (01) in binary, the result `10 & 01` is therefore 0 .

bool(2) convert 2 to true , is 01 in binary, and `01 & 01` is 01.